# Return values shows undefined in recursion

Tags: javascript

I am facing some problem with my javascript code.In my code, the return function is:

```
        var datas = {};
        datas['results'] = [];
        var j = 0;
        function brand(j) {

            if (j >= data.result[0].brand.length) {
                //console.log(datas);
                return brand(j + 1);
            }
            Brand.findById(data.result[0].brand[j], function (err1, result1) 
              {

                datas['results'][j] = {
                    brand: result1.brand_name,
                    dosage: result1.dosage_id
                };

                brand(j + 1);
                //console.log(datas);
            });
            //console.log(datas);
        }
        value = brand(j);
        console.log(value);
```

On printing the output on console i.e.

```
console.log(datas)
```

I get the expected output, but when I take return value it shows undefined

```
value = brand(j);
console.log(value); // value is undefined
```

Can someone guide me with the problem?
Thanks a ton

Comment: Can you give us more code context here? This code has a lot of problems 1) datas is undefined 2) brand is undefined.

Comment: okk .wait a minute.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using recursion over an iterative solution?

Comment: no..not a specific reason

Comment: Even though there is a way to modify your recursive solution to return the result, I agree with @kngroo that it's simpler (and therefore preferable) to use an iterative solution instead.

Comment: It would make more sense to use an iterative solution, but for the sake of experimentation and learning, It's just fine to try to do this with recursion.

Comment: will you please help me for this problem.?

Comment: Can you please include what it is exactly that you're trying to achieve with this function? All you're doing is returning the original object if some value is larger than the length of `datas.result[0].brand` Are you just trying to solve for j? As in get the length of datas.result[0].brand?

Comment: yes..it am providing my full problem

Comment: this is my full code.

Answer (score 1):

You are altering the data object itself, so that's the reason console.log(datas) work. Also, for the recursion to work, you need to

```
return brand(j+1)
```

Assuming the rest of your code is correct

Edit: After you posted the rest of your code, it becomes clear your problem is with asynchronous code. Basically, brand function is returning nothing to value, but it keeps running. You have couple ways of fixing this, as I don't know what stack you are in, I'd suggest taking a look at some promise library

Comment: it become infinite loop...but the gives the correct answer

Comment: It becomes an infinite loop because you are not properly stepping out of the recursion. In other words: the following line is not working the way it should.

if (j >= data.result[0].brand.length) {

Comment: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: @RupeshYadav as iagowp explained, you did not define a correct and reliable exit condition. This is what makes recursions difficult to comprehend. The answer iagowp provided is correct though.

Comment: no.i checked my condition   (j >= data.result[0].brand.length){...}  ..there is no problem in condition.. .

Comment: @RupeshYadav see https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eGLQWG for a working example.

Comment: If your condition is correct, than some of your code on other stuff must be breaking it.
i just checked it, it runs normally
https://repl.it/McTn/0

Comment: @iagowp but if there is problem in my condition,then how the code inside that condition shows corrrect answer

Comment: Your problem is with the asynchronous nature of javascript. Try reading about async code and promises. Basically, your code is setting the value of value before the function ended running, so it goes as undefined. The condition itself is fine, the problem is the async code ( this function is async => Brand.findById(data.result[0].brand[j], function (err1, result1)  ) It even accepts a callback as an argument

Comment: thnx..i will try it.